# SUM() dentro de CASE()

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta como la siguiente

```sql
SELECT SUM(CASE
               WHEN SUM(o_items.UNITS * items.PRICE) < 50 AND delivery.NAME = 'ORDINARY DELIVERY' THEN 3.95
               WHEN SUM(o_items.UNITS * items.PRICE) < 50 AND delivery.NAME = 'URGENT DELIVERY' THEN 7.5
    END) total

FROM ORDER_ITEMS o_items
         LEFT JOIN ORDERS orders ON orders.ID = o_items.ORDER_ID
         LEFT JOIN DELIVERY_TYPES delivery ON delivery.ID = orders.DELIVERY_TYPE_ID
         LEFT JOIN ITEM_REFERENCES items ON items.ID = o_items.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID
```

Pero me da error

> ERROR 1111 (HY000) at line 5: Invalid use of group function

Comment: Estás usando `SUM` dentro de otro `SUM`, eso no se puede. Revisa la lógica y plantéalo de forma diferente.

Comment: No funciona, ¿qué quieres hacer? en términos funcionales. El código se puede explicar por sí mismo, pero cuando funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Voy a intentar re-escribirla:

```
SELECT SUM(n_total.total) as total 
FROM (
SELECT ( CASE WHEN total < 50 AND delivery.NAME = 'ORDINARY 
DELIVERY' THEN 3.95
WHEN total < 50 AND delivery.NAME = 'URGENT DELIVERY' THEN 7.5 
END) total
FROM 
(SELECT
SUM(o_items.UNITS*items.PRICE)  total, o_item.ORDER_ID
FROM ORDER_ITEMS o_items 
LEFT JOIN ITEM_REFERENCES items ON items.ID = 
o_items.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID GROUP BY o_item.ORDER_ID) n_items 
LEFT JOIN ORDERS orders ON orders.ID = n_items.ORDER_ID
LEFT JOIN DELIVERY_TYPES delivery ON delivery.ID = 
orders.DELIVERY_TYPE_ID) n_total
```

Lo que he hecho es no intentar hacer todos los cálculos en una consulta porque para este caso es imposible totalizar y agrupar todo a la vez.

En cambio, he primero sacado el total del precio, luego he juntado la información de las órdenes y filtrado por los tipos y finalmente en la consulta externa he hecho la sumatoria de todo.

No he probado que funcione, pero espero que te ayude a la hora de plantear este tipo de reportes.

Saludos